# Google+ Login with Play Services 6.5.87 (GoogleApiClient) - Android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

In Play Services 6.1.71 I was using:

`mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(this,this,this).setActions("http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity", "http://schemas.google.com/BuyActivity").setScopes(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN, Scopes.PROFILE).build();`

But in Google Play Services 6.5.87, Google suggest to change PlusClient to GoogleApiClient.Builder instead. But I'm not able to get user info as before:

```
mPlusClient.getAccountName()
```

or

```
mPlusClient.getCurrentPerson()
```

How can I retrieve the user info? I think Google documentation is out of date. 
Hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **GoogleApiClient**, not **PlusClient**. Sample:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .build();
```

To *getAccountName()* use **Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient)**

To *getCurrentPerson()* use **Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)**

Answer (score 0):

Very nice [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) how to implement login with GoogleApiClient ...
Since it is whole tutorial I do not copy it here.